# Is this sequence formed by basis of Bergman space in $ l^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, bergman-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following Proposition (see image)  in S. Krantz's Book on Bergman Kernal.

I have two questions:

(1) Let $A^2 (\Omega) $ be bergman space.
Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be it's complete ON basis.

Fix some $ z \in \Omega $.
Does ${\phi_n (z) \in l^2}$  ?

we can show $sup \space {\phi_n (z) } $ is bounded by the following result:

"For $L$ compact subset of $\Omega $ ,
$ sup \space |f(z)| \leq C_{L} ||f|| $ as z varies over $L$.

Take {z} to be compact set.

But no idea how will we show it's in l2.

(2) How did we reach second step in the proof in the image ?
I think the author is using the fact that
$ ||a_n||  = sup \{ |<a_n,b_n>| : ||b_n||=1 ,b_n \in l^2\} $ ?

Is that the case ?

But we priori don't know if $a_n \in l^2$  or not?

What is happeing here? Any help is appreciated.
[image]